# child div getting hidden when parent has position:fixed

Tags: html, css

The problem is quite weird and hence I took help of images to explain it.

**Image 1:** (Refer below image) Here the side bar doesn't have any position explicitly set and popup has

```
.popup{ 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 900100; 
}
```

My pop up is positioned over side bar and content section, so far so good.

[image: Pop up is shown correctly]

**Image 2:** On content scroll, I make my side bar to be positioned fixed so that side bar doesn't scroll when only content in being scrolled. Hence side bar gets below styles.

```
.sideBar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px
}
```

Now, when the pop up is opened, it hides behind the content section, as shown in below image.[image]

I tried changing positions on elements etc but nothing seems to help. Please provide some approach. I don't want popup to hide behind the content section.

Comment: Could you show your code or create a JSfiddle so that we're able to check your code. For now maybe try adding a `z-index` to the sidebar?

Comment: @Deathstorm, your suggestion has helped. Thanks

Comment: Great! goodluck with coding!

Answer (score 0):

Without your code or a fiddle it's difficult, however please make sure your popup **and** sidebar have a higher z-index than the content section.

Answer (score 0):

**How I fixed it:**

1. `z-index` of sidebar was made greater than `z-index` of content. (Credits - @Deathstorm)
2. Added `position: fixed` to my pop up `div`.